# C # create report from html template using resource file

Tags: c#, .net

I'm building a report from a HTML template that is coming from a resource (resx) file

The report is built up in sections in C# for example this is the report header

```
CustomerReportTemplate.Header.Replace("{Customer Name}", customer);
```

I need to replace part of the report given this html and set the image source depending on the properties of the customer.   For example

```
if(Customer.asset.any())
{
   // pass in this markup  <img src="pass.png">  replacing {customer asset} token 
   // something like....CustomerReportTemplate.Details.Replace("{customer asset}",     image);
}
else
{
   // pass in this markup  <img src="fail.png">  replacing {customer asset} token  
}
```

and loop through all customers building the report section below

```
  <td >
    {customer asset}
  </td>
  <td >
    {customer CRB check}
  </td>
  <td >
    {customer ID check}
  </td>
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried any of the HTML template engines? https://github.com/jehugaleahsa/mustache-sharp#readme

Comment: Thanks yes I have however I have to use the approach above,  there are not that many token replacements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a templating library, like [Mustache](http://mustache.github.io/). It has implementations for many platforms, including .NET. We've been using in in our projects and the performance footprint is quite small.

Comment: Thanks but I have to use this approach with resource files and HTML.

Comment: Presumably you can still use this approach but just using the template library for doing the rendering.

Comment: @user3721710, you can load the HTML file from resources and pass it to Mustache along with your arguments. It just saves you the hassle of finding and replacing substrings yourself.